# How to read full file with pg_read_file and missing_ok=true?

Tags: postgresql, shared-libraries

All the following uses of [pg_read_file()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html) are running fine:

```sql
select pg_read_file('myFile.txt'); -- ok full file
select pg_read_file('myFile-notExists',0,10,true); -- NULL is Ok!
```

But these are problematic:

```sql
select pg_read_file('myFile-notExists.txt'); -- ERROR... It is not what I need
select pg_read_file('myFile.txt',0,10,true); -- ok not null, but need full file!
```

... I try to solve the problem with a wrap function:

```sql
CREATE or replace FUNCTION pg_read_file(f text, missing_ok boolean) RETURNS text AS $$
  SELECT pg_read_file(f,0,922337203,missing_ok) 
   -- the max 9223372036854775807 is  too large, also 9223372036854775800, ....
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

But it say *"ERROR:  requested length too large"* for tests on maximum length... So I using aleatory constant. **Question1**: what the "max file size" value?

```sql
select pg_read_file('myFile-notExists.txt',true); -- Ok! NULL is what I need
select pg_read_file('myFile.txt',true); -- Ok! full file.
```

---

**Question2**: is there another way to solve this problem?

At standard PostgreSQL v12 `\df pg_read_file`  says:

```
   Schema   |     Name     | Result data type |      Argument data types      | Type
------------+--------------+------------------+-------------------------------+------
 pg_catalog | pg_read_file | text             | text                          | func
 pg_catalog | pg_read_file | text             | text, bigint, bigint          | func
 pg_catalog | pg_read_file | text             | text, bigint, bigint, boolean | func
```

**Why `pg_read_file(text,boolean)` is not in the pg_catalog?** It will produce some inconsistence with other modules or extensions?

Comment: What do you want to happen if the size of the file is larger than the maximum size of a PostgreSQL value?

Comment: Hi @jjanes, a  file *"larger than the maximum size"* is a big problem, we must avoid it... But the *length* parameter (second bigint) enforces a limit. Ideal is "free size" or the maximum of the filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Wiki, please EDIT to enhance this answer!

PS: check also  [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67367645/287948), performance questions and [this alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67533757/287948).

---

**It is a `pg_read_file()` bug**... And for a workaround, **no really good solution** without race condition (remembered before by @jjanes). Real-time applications need some caution.

Here a change of approach, to retrieve `pg_stat_file`'s information, avoiding loss of CPU.

It's a matter of taste, I think RECORD is ugly to work with, I prefer JSONb.

Imagine a cenario where you are working with JSONb, for example building back-end with [PostgREST](http://postgrest.org)...

### Reusing pg_stat_file

```sql
CREATE or replace FUNCTION jsonb_read_stat_file(
  f text,
  missing_ok boolean DEFAULT false
) RETURNS JSONb AS $f$
  SELECT j || jsonb_build_object( 'file',f,  'content',pg_read_file(f) )
  FROM to_jsonb( pg_stat_file(f,missing_ok) ) t(j)
  WHERE j IS NOT NULL
$f$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

To to get only content, emulating pure `read_file(x,true)`, you can use `jsonb_read_stat_file('/tmp/text.txt',true)->>'content'`.

---

Example of use:

```sh
echo "Hello world!" > /tmp/text.txt
psql mydb -c "SELECT jsonb_read_stat_file('/tmp/text-ERROR.txt',true) IS NULL" # true
psql mydb -c "SELECT jsonb_read_stat_file('/tmp/text.txt',true)"
```

```json
 {
   "file": "/tmp/text.txt", 
   "size": 13, 
   "isdir": false, 
   "access": "2020-08-09T14:44:28+00:00",
   "change": "2020-08-09T14:44:28+00:00", 
   "content": "Hello world!\n", 
   "creation": null, 
   "modification": "2020-08-09T14:44:28+00:00"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using pg_stat_file to test its existence?

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION pg_read_file(f text, missing_ok boolean) RETURNS text AS $$
  SELECT case 
     when pg_stat_file(f,missing_ok) is NULL then NULL 
     else pg_read_file(f) end
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

There is a race condition here that the file could disappear after the pg_stat_file but before the pg_read_file, leading to an error rather than  NULL return.

Comment: Thanks, you solved but, besides that race condition, the CPU waste on `pg_stat_file()` work... **Seems a bug** on `pg_read_file` function.